# How can I use value of the id column as default value of another non-nullable column when using postgresql-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, rails-postgresql

Here's one example where such a requirement comes up:

Suppose we have a table 'sample' in our database which has a column 'col1' and an auto-incremental 'id' column.
We want the default value of 'col1' to be taken as the value of the 'id' column. How do I do that?

I am using rails to write the migration script which will create the table in my postgres databse.

Comment: As far as I know, you don't get this level of control at the database level, but it would be easy to o at the model level using callbacks or validators.

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.up
    Yourmodel.update_all("updated_at=created_at")
end
```

Something like this in your migration script can help you.